# How to use ZINCRBY with predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm using Predis to connect to a Reddis server, and am trying to use ZINCRBY.
The rawcommand is apparently not supported anymore, and I can't get the following to work:

```
$cmdSet = $redis->createCommand('ZINCRBY');
$foo = array($stemwijzerid, $answernumber.'-'.$answer);
$cmdSet->setArguments($foo);
$cmdSetReply = $redis->executeCommand($cmdSet);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply using zincrby:

`$redis->zincrby('myzset', 2. "one")`

Comment: I found this later indeed, the docs not being up to date is a major pain. Thanks.